# Restroom fan switch replacement

Tags: electrical, switch, exhaust-fan

[image: picture of switch]What type of switch would I replace this with? It controls a restroom fan/vent with a light. The light (even though it's part of the restroom fan) is controlled by a separate light switch. Pictured is the cover and the details under the switch. I don't mind if it would be replaced with a regular switch or something similar to this... Whatever is easiest! We know next to nothing about electric so every detail will help. Thank you!

Comment: Think that is a humidistat and probably automatic(it turns on/off the fan by itself).  Question you need to ask is it the fan or humidistat giving the problem.

Comment: Looks like a manual timer/switch to me; on the left you can see the dial markings for "minutes on" where there is (or used to be) a rotating knob. It would not be unusual for Honeywell to call a timer/switch a "Humidity Control" and sell it for washrooms. Should be able to replace with a heavy-duty switch (motor load).

Answer (score 1):

### What you're after is a modern humidistatic vent fan control

The Honeywell H46 series is (still) their line of dedicated humidistats, so we'll want to replace this with something capable of humidistatic control.  Provided this is controlling an ordinary vent fan, a Leviton IPHS5-1L in a suitable junction box will do the trick, provided neutral is available at the switch.  Other options in the electronic category include the Broan-NuTone DD500 and the Enerlites DWHS; Enerlites also makes the DWHOS if you want PIR functionality in addition to the fan controller.

If you do not have neutral at the box, though, you'll need to use a mechanical control instead of a digital.  The Honeywell H46C1166 is the current replacement for your part in the Honeywell product line; you can also use an Air King DH55 if you can't find the Honeywell dehumidistat, although neither provides any extra timer functionality, just humidity-based control.

Answer (score 0):

I will take a SWAG as I do not know what country you are in or your local codes. Doing the following to code should be easy to do.First turn off the power, then remove the two units from the box, then take pictures of the wiring so you can put it back if needed. There should be two wires to each device, one goes to both and is probably spliced or looped from device to device. This should be the hot wire. The other wire to each switch goes to the fan and light. Take some tape and mark each one so you know what you have later. Remove the device that controls the light and place those two wires on a switch. Then remove the two wires from the humidistat and place them on the other switch you purchased or a new humidistat. Put the devices in the box, add the cover and all should work after you turn the power back on.